# How to load a pickle file containing scikit-learn model in a Flask application?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, scikit-learn

I'm trying to create a simple Flask-based web application where a user enters some text and receive a sentiment classification of it. I'm having trouble loading a pickle file I saved after training a model using scikit-learn. The file I'm trying to load is `tfidf_vectorizer_train.pkl`, which should have loaded when I make the function call to `load_tfidf_model`. Whenever I run the application locally, I get the following error

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'transform'

which I suspect is arising from the fact that the model failed to load and the global variable `tfidf_model` remains as None type.

If it helps, the current directory looks like

```
├── ml_app.py
├── models
│   └── tfidf_vectorizer_train.pkl
├── templates
│   └── main.html
```

where `ml_app.py` contains the code below

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template 
from sklearn.externals import joblib

app = Flask(__name__)

models_directory = 'models'

tfidf_model = None


def load_tfidf_model():

    global tfidf_model

    tfidf_model = joblib.load('{}/tfidf_vectorizer_train.pkl'.format(models_directory))


@app.route('/') 
def my_form():
    return render_template('main.html')


@app.route('/', methods=['POST']) 
def my_form_post():

    text = request.form['text']

    # clean using tfidf
    comment_term_doc = tfidf_model.transform([text])
    processed_text = comment_term_doc.toarray()

    return render_template('main.html', text=text, processed_text=processed_text)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        load_tfidf_model()
        print("Model loaded")

    except Exception as e:
        print("Model loading failed")
        print(str(e))

    app.run()
```

Answer (score 2):

As you have obviously concluded, you need to call `load_tfidf_model` before you can call the `my_form_post` routed method. One possible conclusion is that `joblib.load` is failing. You do not check the return value anywhere.

Since you don't report any exceptions I assume none have occurred.

The [`joblib.load` documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/generated/joblib.load.html#joblib.load) suggests any Python type can be returned, so you will probably need to look at the code that creates the file it's loading.

A stylistic matter: rather than use a global, have `load_tfidf_model` return the value that `joblib.load` returns, and save it in the calling code (where you don't need to declare it global). Globals are not a good way to communicate between functions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I figured out the problem. When I start the server using `flask run` I get the error that the model has not been loaded. But when I start it using `python ml_app.py` (name of the app), it works and it runs everything under __name__ == '__main__', which is what I need to load the model.